# Removing an element from a nested list within an object using range-based loops

Tags: c++

I'm using C++20.

I have an object `MyObject` that contains a variable `std::set<std::set<int>> nestedSet`. I need to iterate through `nestedSet` and remove from the second-level sets an element that matches a search criteria. So far, I've tried the implementations:

```
void MyObject::removeFromNestedSet(int criteria) {
    for(auto s : nestedSet){
        std::erase_if(s, [&criteria](int i){return i == criteria;});
    }
}
```

and

```
void MyObject::removeFromNestedSet(int criteria) {
    for(auto s : nestedSet){
        auto it = s.find(criteria);
        if(it != s.end()){
            s.erase(it, s.end());
        }
    }
}
```

Viewing the code progression with a debugger, I can see that within the frame of the `removeFromNestedSet` function, the element in the set matching the criteria IS removed. However, this removal is not reflected when observing the `this->nestedSet` object.

I haven't worked with C++ in a few years, but I suspect this is an issue with needing the range-based loop to point to the actual nested sets within `nestedSet` rather than a copy of the nested set?

Comment: Are you trying to scrub everything in the set from the match to the 'end' element?

Comment: Elements of a `std::set` are constant, because changing them could break the imposed ordering.  Remove the inner set, change it, then re-add it.

Comment: Note that removing an inner set inside the range-based `for` loop will be a fatal mistake.

Comment: Why you declare s as a copy in `for(auto s : nestedSet)` ? **Obviously, it should be `for(auto &s : nestedSet)` if you want to access original object. Modifying the copy is only a waste of time!

Comment: @Phil1970 `for(auto &s : nestedSet)` will not allow modification to the original set either.

Comment: Do you really need the outer container to be an `std::set`? Perhaps an `std::vector` is also suited. This would solve the issue.

Comment: @ph3rin Problem is, modifying the inner set would modify the outer set. For example, if you have a set {"ac","b"} and you want to remove 'a', you would end up with {"c","b"} but that breaks the set's ordering, because it should look like this: {"b","c"}. Sets are ordered lexicographically, IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having difficulty because a `std::set`'s elements are always `const`.

This is because a `std::set`'s elements are always ordered by their values.  Changing a value could violate the order.

You must remove each element from your outer `std::set` before you can modify it.

```
void MyObject::removeFromNestedSet(int criteria) {
    std::set<std::set<int>> newNestedSet;

    while ( ! nestedSet.empty() ) {
       // Remove an inner set, so it can be modified
       auto setNode = nestedSet.extract( nestedSet.begin() );

       // Modify the set
       std::erase_if(setNode.value(), [&](int i){return i == criteria;});

       // Place the result in a new set
       newNestedSet.insert(std::move(setNode));
    }

    nestedSet = std::move(newNestedSet);
}
```

This solution doesn't make any copies of your data **and** preserves the integrity of any pointers or references to your stored `int`s.

Note that your sets may be in a different order after your modification.

Answer (score 1):

Several options.

1. If you insist on that particular data-structure, you'll have to copy the entire thing over to a new set and then swap/move that with/into the member.

```
  std::set<std::set<int>> dest;
  for (auto const& n: nestedSet) {
    std::set<int> ndest;
    for (int i: n) {
      if (i != criteria) {
        ndest.insert(i);
      }
    }
    dest.emplace(std::move(ndest));
  }
  nestedSet = std::move(dest);
```

Needless to say, this is terrible.

2. But maybe you don't really need to be dealing with a set to begin with. Often a vector is the better choice: `std::vector<std::set<int>> nestedSet;` (maybe even the inner set can be a vector!).
   Then you do the algorithm like you tried:

```
  for(auto& s : nestedSet) {
  //      ^--------- important, or you would be modifying a copy
    std::erase_if(s, [&criteria](int i){return i == criteria;});
  }
```

3. If you absolutely need a set, you could have an `std::set<std::unique_ptr<std::set<int>>> nestedSet`

```
  for(auto const& p : nestedSet) {
    // p is an std::unique_ptr<std::set<int>> const&
    std::erase_if(*p, [&criteria](int i){return i == criteria;});
  }
```

Of course this does introduce yet another layer of indirection, but with two nested sets this almost doesn't matter anymore.